# What field combines Complex Analysis and Measure Theory?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I am in the process of choosing a topic for my master's thesis. Until now I have studied a lot of real and complex analysis. My favourite areas of study has been measure theory and complex analysis. I am looking for suggestions of topics which combine the two.

All suggestions are appriciated.

Comment: Loewner process? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution

Comment: Quasi-conformal (just google the word) mappings combine very well the two subjects.

Comment: I am currently looking further into both these topics. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: see this paper on probability theory where complex and functional analysis is highly used.
(1):https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.4786.pdf
Also look at the references of this paper. The regular variation theory and complex analysis are really related.

Comment: @Did Once took a course on SLE and the free field under somebody named Werner. It definitely had a lot of heavy complex analysis (well beyond the basic graduate course), as well as a lot of stochastic calculus. But there was not much measure theory at all.

Answer (score 2):

I support the topic of Kahler manifolds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold

In particular, for example, study to Volume minimizers...

Comment: This seems quite advanced. Do you think it is overcomeable during my 5th year?